# Take snapshot of DB table row?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to take a snap shot of a row in a MySQL table.

The reason being, if someone buys a product. I want to take a snapshot of that product to store for the order.

It needs to be a snapshot to maintain data integrity. If I just assign the product to the order, if the product changes in the future the order will show those changes. For example if the price changes, the order will now load the new data and say that it sold the product at its new price rather than what the price was when the order was placed. So a snapshot needs to be assigned to the order instead.

The way I did this in the past was having 2 tables, one for products, and one for snapshots of products. The snapshot had every column as the regular table plus extra colums like `order_id`

I had a script to take a snapshot that automatically looked at the fields in the regular table and tried to do an insert into the same fields into the snapshot table.

The biggest problem with that approach is that, if I added a column to the regular table and forgot to add the same column to the snapshot table; the script would try to insert data into a non existent field and fail.

I also disliked the idea of having 2 tables that were nearly identical. I think maybe figuring out a way to use one table for both purposes might be better.

---

So I am wondering if there is a known method I am unaware of to solve this issue?

My previous project used no framework but my next one will be using CakePHP if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way of handling this would be to roll the "snapshot" information into an `orders_products` table. So if you have an order, store the total price, tax, etc. information in a single row on the `orders` table and reference that `order_id` on your `orders_products` table. On your `orders_products` table, you can have `order_id, product_id, price, quantity, discount` and whatever else you need.

Comment: +1 Great suggestion, a definite improvement over my design. I will wait and see if there are any other good suggestions before I mark an answer though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your previous is fine.  But that you just need to do more testing to ensure that you don't forget to add the new fields to the snapshot table. Seems like a basic test that would be easy to do.  The other alternative is to just use a big text field, and store the snapshot as XML.  This will let you store the snapshot regardless of if the schema changes.  Depending on how much you want to query this data, it may or may not work for you.

Also you may not want to store every field, as it may just take up extra space. For instance, if you have the location of the image file of the item, you may not want to store that, as it may not be important at a later date.  You could try querying information_schema to query which fields are in the snapshot table, and only copy the available fields.

Comment: Really? Storing xml strings in a relational DB is a NOT A GOOD IDEA(tm) - If you go this route store the serialized array to a text field. Better yet would be to store the obvious sale line item data in the join table for the orders_products table and write a valid model for the join table. Remember to use the 'with' key in your relationships and you should be off to a good start. (I would submit a new answer but this is the same idea as what treeface is suggesting)

Comment: MS thought it was useful enough to add a whole to datatype to store XML in a field. MySQL is also adding a lot of functionality for querying and working with XML data stored in a database field.  Regardless of whether or not it's a "Good Idea (TM)" a lot of people seem to be doing it and it seems to solve a lot of people's problems in a very good way.

Comment: Storing relational data as a string within another relational storage layer is considered even by MS to be a bad thing according to the MSSQL docs. Just because they let you do it doesn't mean you should - just that enough people *were* that they decided to support it.

Comment: Well, obviously, they have an internal conflict then.  Because on one hand, the docs say you shouldn't store relational data as a string in a database field.  On the other hand, they when through the very intentional process of designing an entire feature, adding a whole new data type, and a whole bunch of functions, for the express purpose of storing relational data as a string inside a database field. So while it may be listed as a bad idea somewhere in the documentation, they sure went through a lot of effort to help you do it.